# What do you think about this guide in spanish? (In progress)

Tags: ros, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to make a basic guide for using ROS in spanish. It is some like a traduction of wiki, some info from other sources and a little of experience I had. In difference of wiki documentation and tutorials, I want this guide shows concepts beside with execution of examples. It's just an approach that I want to prove.

So I want to receive any suggestion, correction or whatever thing you think to improve this doc.

[The document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Xd5VPLDCIuMRb6gnYd-QXBgnBdIXNwjPsQnWtiaCOlE/pub)

Thanks for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66471/what-do-you-think-about-this-guide-in-spanish?-(in-progress)/) by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 756 on 2013-07-02

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2013-07-26**:
good job, ROS needs to be showed in latin america, this is a good start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, thank you for taking the time to provide documentation in spanish! I just looked at the wiki, and it looks like we don't yet have spanish translations; your work looks like a really good start at explaining ROS!

I'm curious what your goals with this document are, and why you're choosing to do it this way rather than in the wiki framework. I'm biased towards the wiki, because it allows other people to build on your efforts and makes it easier for it to be a living document. The english-language wiki can also provide a guide for what other people have found it necessary to explain. Plus, it's (hopefully!) where people will look first, so your work would probably have a much bigger impact.

However, I can understand wanting to keep it separate if your eventual goal is to publish something like "ROS by Example" (http://www.pirobot.org).

At this point, it looks like your document corresponds to a hybrid of the introduction  (http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Introduction) and conceptual overview (http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Concepts), followed by the installation/configuration instructions. My spanish probably isn't good enough to help with generating content, but I can read well enough to help with adding your content to the wiki, if this is a use of it that you'd be OK with.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-07-02**:
Note - a Q&A forum like this isn't really suited to this type of discussion, but I'm not sure that it suits ros-users either ... Hopefully somebody else will come along and tell us where to take it.

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-07-03**:
Hi!, thanks for your response. I though in this before posting this here, but between answers.ros.org and mail list, I decided to post it here because is more likely to search information here than in ros-users. Eventually I hope to help in translating wiki into spanish.

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-07-03**:
OK, cool! I'm glad to hear that you hope to incorporate this into the wiki - please let me know if I can help in any way! I'd welcome the chance to learn some more technical spanish =)  If you want to contact me directly, my e-mail is lindzey[at]gmail

**Comment by [agonzamart](https://answers.ros.org/users/3277/agonzamart/) on 2013-07-04**:
I am making my final master project using Ros I am Spanish and I am making the document in Spanish much of it is explaining the use of Ros, navigation and localization libraries, simulation using gazebo... so I think I can help you with this.

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-07-04**:
Hi @agonzamart, part of the idea I have, is start explaining simulation 2D with stage, and after this start a chapter of 3D simulation. It would be great if you can help with this :D

**Comment by [agonzamart](https://answers.ros.org/users/3277/agonzamart/) on 2013-07-05**:
Ok @gustavo.velascoh I am now just beginning to write that part of my thesis so we keep in touch and I surely can help you with that if we are able to help to develop an spanish wiki it would be so great! :)

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-07-05**:
@gustavo.velascoh nice work! Just wanted to inform there are [German](http://www.ros.org/wiki/de) and [Japanese](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ja) versions on the same wiki.